# Text Boxes not giving me a sum, only the values

Tags: javascript, asp.net

UPDATE:::::::
I've added some more text boxes to be summed and now the value in my txtTotalCuAB text box is displaying "NaN" so sorry to bother you all again, but some input would be certainly appreciated.

All, I have two text boxes that are being calculated and the SUM is display in a third text box. For some reason, I'm not getting a sum I'm just getting the values.

Here is my code with the javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() 
    {
        var txtCu4Row= form1.txtCu4Row.value;
        var txtCu5Row= form1.txtCu5Row.value;
        form1.txtTotalCuAB.value = txtCu4Row + txtCu5Row;
    }
</script>
```

Here is where I'm calling my function once the value in my last text box changes:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCu5Row" runat="server" Width="25px" Heighth="20" Height="18px" 
        CssClass="style40" CausesValidation="True" OnChange="myFunction()"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Are you trying to sum numbers that are entered?

Comment: strange function implementation. suppose sth with  parseInt(txtCu4Row)+ parseInt(txtCu5Row)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the addition of two numbers entered into your text box, you'll need to parse the strings as ints first.

Try:

```
form1.txtTotalCuAB.value = parseInt(txtCu4Row) + parseInt(txtCu5Row);
```

Before you do that, I would also add some validation to the text boxes to make sure the user entered a number. Otherwise your results from parseInt will be NaN.

Comment: You all are so great! I suppose I was parsing incorrectly. Once again, thank you all so much. My question is answered.

Comment: You're very welcome. please remember to accept or upvote the answer.

Comment: I don't think I have enough points to up-vote, yet, but I'll certainly try.

Comment: Since you asked the question, you can accept an answer that worked for you, regardless of rep

Comment: So I've added some more text boxes to be summed and now the value in my txtTotalCuAB text box is displaying "NaN" so sorry to bother you all again, but some input would be certainly appreciated.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction()
     {
        var txtCu2Row = form1.txtCu2Row.Value;
        var txtCu3Row = form1.txtCu3Row.Value;
        var txtCu4Row= form1.txtCu4Row.value;
        var txtCu5Row= form1.txtCu5Row.value;
        form1.txtTotalCuAB.value = parseInt(txtCu2Row)+parseInt(txtCu3Row)+parseInt(txtCu4Row)+parseInt(txtCu5Row);


    }

Answer (score 0):

Need to use parseInt

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() 
    {
        var txtCu4Row= form1.txtCu4Row.value;
        var txtCu5Row= form1.txtCu5Row.value;
        form1.txtTotalCuAB.value = parseInt(txtCu4Row) + parseInt(txtCu5Row);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Form values are treated as strings. when you do their sum you get string concatenation not integer sum. you need to do parseInt

```
function myFunction() 
{
    var txtCu4Row= parseInt(form1.txtCu4Row.value);
    var txtCu5Row= parseInt(form1.txtCu5Row.value);
     if(!isNaN(txtCu4Row) && !isNaN(txtCu5Row))
      {
        form1.txtTotalCuAB.value = txtCu4Row + txtCu5Row;
      }
     else 
     {
       //handle case when form value is not a number
       console.log("please enter numbers");
     }


}
```